# Django: sorl-thumbnail cache file is not deleted in production environment

Tags: django, amazon-s3, sorl-thumbnail

I use `django-cleanup`, `sorl-thumbnail` in my `Django` project.

I have a model like this:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Variation(BaseModel):
    image = ImageField(upload_to=draft_img_upload_location)
```

And I use signal for sorl-thumbnail like this (recommanded by https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup):

```
from django_cleanup.signals import cleanup_pre_delete

def sorl_delete(**kwargs):
    from sorl.thumbnail import delete
    delete(kwargs['file'])

cleanup_pre_delete.connect(sorl_delete)
```

So, In local environment, belows work:
    1. When I delete `Variation` model in **ADMIN PAGE**, it deletes BOTH image file and image cache(created by sorl-thumbnail).
    2. When I change just image file with other image in **ADMIN PAGE**, it delete BOTH 'prior image file' and 'prior image cache file(created by sorl-thumbnail)'.

In production environment, I used `AWS S3` and `cloudfront` for managing `static` and `media` file. So all sorl-thumbnail cache image files are stored in `S3`. But whenever I changed the image file with other image file in **ADMIN PAGE**, the prior image cache file(created by sorl-thumbnail) still remained.

Lets say that `sorl-thumbnail` image url is `https://example.cloudfront.net/cache/da/75/abcdefg_i_am_cached_image.jpg` (from Google development tool).
In this case, there were two image files exist in `S3`: `abcdefg.jpg` and  `/da/75/abcdefg_i_am_cached_image.jpg`
I changed `abcdefg.jpg` with the other image. Then, it completely deleted `abcdefg.jpg` in `S3 storage`.

Now, I accessed `https://example.cloudfront.net/cache/da/75/abcdefg_i_am_cached_image.jpg` in my browser and guess what! It showed this `sorl-thumbnail` cached images in this time!
Strange thing happened in `S3 storage`. When I tried to check whether  `abcdefg_i_am_cached_image.jpg` exists in path `/da/75`, there was no directory named `75` right below the `da` folder!

In short, `abcdefg_i_am_cached_image.jpg` still remained in my `S3 storage`!

I don't know why this happened only in production environment...

This is part of `settings` only for production mode.

**settings.py**

```
from .partials import *

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*", ]


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'spacegraphy.storage.S3PipelineCachedStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get("AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN")
AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = 'https'
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'

STATIC_URL = "https://this-is-my-example.cloudfront.net/"

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'storages',
    'collectfast'
]

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
```

**storage.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin, ManifestFilesMixin

from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class S3PipelineManifestStorage(PipelineMixin, ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass


class S3PipelineCachedStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```

After spending couple of hours debugging, I found out that `sorl_delete` signal is not called only in **production environment**!!. 
I have no idea why this happened. I think that this one is a main problem.
And sorry for bad english (I'm not native). Really need your help. Thanks

Comment: Where did you place this code "cleanup_pre_delete.connect(sorl_delete)" ? In models.py? Did you try to use weak=False? "cleanup_pre_delete.connect(sorl_delete, weak=False)" Are you sure "connect" method is executed in your productuion env?

Comment: @un1t I placed that code in signals.py inside one of my app. I tried `weak=False` but it doesn't work, either. How can I check `"connect" method is executed in your productuion env?` Other signals(custom signal that I made) work good.